# Activities creation speed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app in wich there are 4 screens, screens are created  after clicking on button, each screen has a new activity, but activities are running too slow (3 seconds for creation). In second activity I have information which depends on first activity, so I can't create activity before the button clicks. Is there any other way to have 4 screens which are created one after another, and speed is fast?

```
package your.pack.namespace;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ParsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

     private Collection<String> title = new LinkedList<String>();
     public Collection<String> desc = new LinkedList<String>();
     public NodeList Items = getNodeList();
     Collection<String> secTitle = new LinkedList<String>();


     Document doc;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setScrollContainer(true);
        ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradientbackground);

        CreateScr(ll,Items);
      }


      private void CreateScr(LinearLayout l1,NodeList btns){


             for(int i=0;i<btns.getLength();i++){
             Element eElement= (Element)btns.item(i);
             this.title.add(getTagValue("title",eElement));
             this.desc.add(getTagValue("description",eElement));

             }
             btnCreate(title,l1);
             this.setContentView(l1);
      }


      public  void btnCreate (Collection<String> name,LinearLayout l1)
      {
          int k=0;
        for(String i:name ){

             Button btnNew = new Button(this);
             btnNew.setId(k);
             //btnNew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottomrow) ;  
             btnNew.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + i + "</b>" +  "<br />"));
             l1.addView(btnNew);
             k++; 
             btnNew.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        this.setContentView(l1);
      }

      public static Document getDocument(String url)
              throws MalformedURLException, IOException, Exception {
             URL documentUrl = new URL(url);
             URLConnection conn = documentUrl.openConnection();

             DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document document;
             InputStream stream = null;
             try {
              stream = conn.getInputStream();
              document = builder.parse(stream);
             } finally {
              if (stream != null) stream.close();
             }
             return document;
            }

        public  NodeList getNodeList (){
            try {
                  doc = getDocument("http://afishadroid.about.od.ua/main.xml");

            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                //Обрабатываем   ошибку   
            }


            NodeList nd = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            return  nd;
        }

        public Element getElement (NodeList nl,int id1){

            Element eElement = (Element)nl.item(id1);
            return eElement;
        }


      protected static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

                Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

            return nValue.getNodeValue();
          }


          public  void onClick(View v) { 

             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
            // intent.putExtra("ID",v.getId());
              startActivity(intent);
              //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class) .putExtra("ID", v.getId()); startActivity(intent);


          }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load your activity fast then you need to do as less as you can in the onCreate. Use AsyncTask to load data which can take a few seconds.

Comment: even if creates an empty activity it takes 3 seconds, maybe there is a way to start all activities when app is creating, and then to pause and resume them???

Comment: How are you creating them now?

Comment: Intent intent = new
 intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.)
 startActivity(intent);

Comment: Try it like this:
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)
   .putExtra("ID", v.getId());
  startActivity(intent);
Does v.getId() does something which could take some time?

Comment: it gets id of pressed button and sends it to the other activity

Comment: And how are you doing that? And did you try my code for starting an Intent instead of your code?

Comment: yeah i tried , nothing changed, i try even empty activity it also takes 3 seconds

Comment: Are you using an emulator or device? If possible try (another) device or restart your emulator.

Comment: Please add all the code you are using in your question. For the empty Activity

Comment: public class SecondActivity extends ParsActivity    {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.
     
 }

Comment: post your onCreate() from ParsActivity

Comment: LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     ll.setScrollContainer(true);
     ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradientbackground);
     
     CreateScr(ll,Items);

Comment: And what are you doing in CreateScr ??

Comment: When second activity doesnt extend firstActivity it starts fast , but i need some data from first activity thats why i nee to extend it

Comment: I think you are not understanding how to pass data between 2 activities. In the onCreate() of the second activity you can simple do:      getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID")
 To get the ID you passed.

Comment: Sorry, but you have to post all of your code in your question above (edit it) so I can understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the data locally(means local data) then it won't take much time but if you are displaying some data that will be fetched from server, try to do that in a separate thread so that your UI thread won't block and once fetching data is done,refresh your screen in UI thread.

Try to finish your onCreate() as soon as possible and do all the calculations and rest in your onResume() or onPause() method.

Comment: even if i create an empty second  activity it takes 3 seconds

Comment: can you post your intent firing code of FirstActivity and onCreate() method of secondActivity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

now i have an empty second activity

Comment: Are you trying this thing on emulator or any android device.

Comment: i think i know where is the problem, it starts fast wneh SecondActivity doesn't extends FirstActivity , but i need to get data from first activity(NodeList)

Comment: In this case you don't need to extend your first activity. just pass the data in a bundle like :

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle .putString("KEY","VALUE");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: i Know but i need to put NodeList in budle

Comment: What is this NodeList and what is the use of this node in your second activity.

Comment: Create a Data model class where you put your nodelist in a hashtable from first activity and restore the same nodelist using same hashtable in your second activity.Thus no need to extend your first activity inside Second.

Comment: I guess the problem is with your extend part. when u extend your first activity inside second activity, you call super.onCreate(bundle) method (inside second activity's onCreate(bundle) method) which in turn calls your first activity's onCreate(bundle) method and hence createScr(ll, Items) gets called again.Thus taking some time to get it done.